# Como criar dois pontos y para um mesmo x?

Tags: python

Olá, eu gostaria de criar uma rotina em python para criar "pontos duplos", onde um mesmo valor de x assumiria dois valores de y para qualquer situação. Usando a seguinte sequência de dados por exemplo:

```
1;5
2;2
3;4
4;10
5;6
```

Plotando esse gráfico como sendo a primeira coluna x e a segunda y, formaria uma linha reta.

O cenário que eu gostaria de chegar seria o seguinte:

```
1;5
1;2
2;2
2;4
3;4
3;10
4;10
4;6
5;6
```

E isso geraria um gráfico retangular. No caso, o valor de x possui o seu respectivo valor de y, porém esse mesmo valor de x também possui o valor de y referente ao seu `"x+1"`, e assim sucessivamente.

Eu tentei criar algo como uma lista, porém sem suceso

```
arquivo = open('vazmed.out', 'rt')
arq = open('vazmed2.out', 'wt')
lista = []
valor_prev = 0
for linha in arquivo:
    campo = linha.split(';')
    i = (campo[0])
    valor = float(campo[1])
    lista.append(valor)
n = len(lista)
for i in range(n-1):
    lista.append([lista[i:][:i], lista[i:][:i+1]])
    arq.write('{};{}\n' .format(i, lista[i]))
arq.close
```

Eu sou novo no python e isso faz parte dos meus estudos, então se alguém conseguir me ajudar e puder explicar o como e o porque eu ficaria agradecido.

EDIT
Código para transformação dos valores positivos em 1 e negativos em -1.

```
arquivo = open('vazdif.out', 'rt')
lista = []
valor_prev = 0
for linha in arquivo:
    campo = linha.split(',')
    cont = int(campo[0])
    vazdif = float(campo[2])
    if vazdif * valor_prev < 0:
        lista.append([lista[-1][0], - lista[-1][1]]) 
    if vazdif < 0:
        lista.append([cont, -1])                                         
    else:
        lista.append([cont, 1])
    valor_prev = vazdif                                                 
fou = open('res_id.out','wt')
for i in lista:
    fou.write('%4d,%8.4f\n' % (i[0],i[1]))
fou.close()
```

O arquivo de saída desse código é o seguinte:

```
   0, -1.0000
   1, -1.0000
   2, -1.0000
   3, -1.0000
   4, -1.0000
   5, -1.0000
   5,  1.0000
   6,  1.0000
   7,  1.0000
   8,  1.0000
   9,  1.0000
  10,  1.0000
  11,  1.0000
  12,  1.0000
  13,  1.0000
  14,  1.0000
  14, -1.0000
  15, -1.0000
  16, -1.0000
  17, -1.0000
  18, -1.0000
  19, -1.0000
  20, -1.0000
```

Como é possível ver, sempre que o valor muda de negativo para positivo, o `i` repete com o valor do `i` anterior. Porém o `i` não faz parte dos dados efetivamente, sendo apenas um índice.

Importante ressaltar que é apenas o índice que vai repetir, não o valor em sí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta do Leafar está correta, mas só irá funcionar se você tratar os dados corretamente.

> Tratando os dados de um arquivo separado por linhas

```
texto = '''1;5
2;-2
3;4.5
4;10
5;6'''
# Para cada linha que tiver na string, gerar uma lista de valores separado por ;
lista = [i.split(';') for i in texto.splitlines()]
print(lista)
# [['1', '5'], ['2', '-2'], ['3', '4.5'], ['4', '10'], ['5', '6']]
```

> Agora é só aplicar a lógica oferecida por Leafar e tratar as strings:

```
m = []
for i in range(len(lista)):
    # Primeiro valor registra como INT e segundo valor registra como FLOAT
    m.append([int(lista[i][0]), float(lista[i][1])])

    if i < len(lista)-1:
        m.append([int(lista[i][0]), float(lista[i+1][1])])
 print(m)
 # [[1, 5.0], [1, -2.0], [2, -2.0], [2, 4.5], [3, 4.5], [3, 10.0], [4, 10.0], [4, 6.0], [5, 6.0]]
```

> E para puxar os dados:

```
for i in m:
    print(f'index = {i[0]}; valor = {i[1]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, o principal problema eh que vc ta usando o indice da lista pra 'guardar' o valor x, mas isso nao eh possivel quando vc tem dois elementos com o mesmo valor x, ja que a lista soh pode ter um valor y guardado naquele indice x.

O outro problema eh que vc ta adicionando todos os pontos originais na lista antes de comecar a adicionar os novos, o que te impede de ordenar os pontos da forma que vc colocou no exemplo.

O comando `lista[i:][:i]` tambem eh bastante estranho. O que vc esta fazendo aqui eh cortar todos os primeiros `i-1` elementos da lista e, dada a lista resultante deste corte, manter apenas os primeiros `i` elementos. Em qualquer caso, essa operacao vai resultar em uma lista, o que nao parece ser oq vc quer ai. Recomendo ate vc fazer alguns experimentos dando print em diferentes valores de `i` como indice para entender melhor como listas funcionam.

Tenta fazer algo nesse sentido:

```
l = [[1,5], [2,2], [3,4], [4,10], [5,6]] # Troque pela leitura do arquivo...

m = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    m.append(l[i])

    if i < len(l)-1:
        m.append([l[i][0], l[i+1][1]])

# Escreva os elementos de m no arquivo...
```

Esse codigo resulta em `m = [[1, 5], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 4], [3, 4], [3, 10], [4, 10], [4, 6], [5, 6]]`, que parece ser o resultado que vc espera.

Comment: Funcionou em partes, acho que talvez eu não tenha explicado direito, porém a primeira coluna, que vai de 1 a 5, não faz parte da lista, então o que eu estou trabalhando efetivamente seria ````[5, 2, 4, 10, 6]````. Porém quando eu tento iterar mais ou menos da mesma forma como você apresentou, aparece o seguinte erro, ````'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'````. E uma outra coisa que talvez esteja dando erro é o fato que a lista que eu possuo não contem apenas números inteiros, ela possui floats e números negativos também, algo por exemplo como isso ````l = [5 ,-2 ,4 ,10.4 ,6]````

Comment: Hmm, certo. Tem como vc dar um exemplo exato de qual comportamento vc ta tentando implementar (por exemplo, qual saida exata vc espera para uma entrada)? E qual comando gera este erro?

Comment: A entrada para isso seria um arquivo (txt por exemplo), onde eu teria determinado número de colunas. Uma dessas colunas seria o ````i````, que nada mais é um índice (tempo por exemplo) do valor da segunda coluna(o qual eu efetivamente quero trabalhar), então dada a entrada da lista que eu usei como exemplo, a saida seria seria o i( que teria dois valores iguais) e o m por exemplo, que seria os valores propriamente ditos. O caso é que um mesmo i (eixo x) vai ter dois valores, o seu próprio e o valor do i relativo ao `````i+1````. E ai se plotar isso o gráfico fica "quadrado".

Comment: O erro que eu comentei está relacionando ao ````m.append([l[i][0], l[i+1][1]])````

Comment: Eu vou fazer um edit no post e colocar um outro código que talvez ajude. Esse código faz quase a mesma coisa. porém a diferença é que nesse eu tinha uma lista de números positivos e negativos, e quando o número era negativo assume o valor -1 na saída, quando positivo assume o valor 1. Porém sempre que ocorre a troca de sinal, cria-se um ponto no mesmo x, porém com o valor do 1 invertido. Então se eu estou em uma sequência negativa, e ai o próximo é positivo, o último x negativo da sequência vai ter dois valores de y, um negativo e um positivo.

Comment: Tem mais ou menos a mesma ideia do que eu tentei fazer, e da forma com ovocê tentou me ajudar. porém era um caso muito específico, -1 e 1, negativo e positivo. Agora eu vou poder ter floats, negativos, positivos e etc